# apply a ordered list of patches using quilt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, patch, quilt

Hi there
I am using a modified version of debian (patched). I have the source code and now I want to see the patched code. 
The patches are in /usr/src/kernel-power-2.6.28/debian/patches] 
and in that folder there is a file called order that contains the ordered list of the patches.

Do you know if there is a way to quilt patch the code with that file?

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

```
export QUILT_PATCHES=/usr/src/kernel-power-2.6.28/debian/patches
export QUILT_SERIES=/usr/src/kernel-power-2.6.28/debian/patches/order
quilt push
```

Comment: sorry it was not that. The output is very long with things like:

Comment: No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 350296
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:

Comment: it worked now.. you need to be in the kernel-power directory when doing the pushing and I was in patches..